# Django get post answers

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  poster = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
  question = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

  post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  post_content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

  is_question = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  .
  .
  .
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.post_title
```

This is going to be question and answer site, just like SO.

If this post is a question, '**is_question**' will be true. 
else if the post is an answer, '**question**' field will refer to the id of the post which is the question and '**is_question**' will be false.

simple, right.

Now I am trying to get all the questions and the related answers, is this possible with one or a few query (without using for loop)?

The following filter will return the questions and some related things only (like number of upvotes, views, post tags):

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    created_date__lte=timezone.now(),
    is_question=1,
    is_published=1
).order_by(
    '-created_date',
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('vote_set', queryset=Vote.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, date_voted__gte=dt_aware), to_attr='user_voted')
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('tags', to_attr='tagss')
).annotate(total_votes=Coalesce(Sum('vote__vote_type'),0)
).annotate(views_num = Count('questionvieaw', distinct=True)
).select_related()
```

Comment: This is very possible. Create a question model that has a property *answers*. Then create an answer model. That leaves the query as Question.objects.all()

Comment: What is inside the answers field? a comma separated list of answer ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. There is already a post_set object available I checked it and it was the answers (I think it's due to *question* property in the model).

So this is the final query:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    created_date__lte=timezone.now(),
    is_question=1,
    is_published=1
).order_by(
    '-created_date',
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('vote_set', queryset=Vote.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, date_voted__gte=dt_aware), to_attr='user_voted')
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('post_set', queryset=Post.objects.filter(
        is_question=0), to_attr='answers')
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('tags', to_attr='tagss')
).annotate(total_votes=Coalesce(Sum('vote__vote_type'),0)
).annotate(views_num = Count('questionvieaw', distinct=True)
).select_related()
```